# Scheme recursive or iterative

Tags: recursion, scheme, iteration

```
(define unique?
  (lambda (l)
    (or (null? l) 
        (null? (cdr l))
        (and (not (in? (car l) (cdr l))) 
             (unique? (cdr l)))))
```

Can someone please tell me if it's an iteratibe or recursive procedure? I guess it is iterative, but I am not sure and I don't know how to explain i

Answer (score 1):

You code is clearly recursive because `unique?` calls `unique?`.  The procedure `unique?` will be iterative if the recursive call occurs in the tail position.  The R6RS standard, see Section 11.20 'Tail calls and tail contexts', details the tail contexts for each syntactic form.  Analyzing your `lambda` we reason as:

- The last expression in a `lambda` is a tail context, so your `or ...` is a tail expression
- The last expression in a `or` is a tail expression, so your `and ...` is a tail expression
- The last expression in a `and` is a tail expression, so your `unique?` is a tail call

Therefore, `unique?` calls itself as a tail call and is thus iterative.

Answer (score 0):

The function is recursive because it calls itself.  Note, however that since it is tail-recursive, it can be compiled to iterative form.

The criteria for a function to be tail recursive is simply that there be nothing to do after the recursive call returns, which is true in your case.

### How to convert a tail-recursive function into a loop

> To transform a tail-recursive function into a while loop, follow the
>   following steps. (There is not an automatic function for converting an
>   arbitrary recursive function into a while loop--you have to convert it
>   into a tail-recursive function first.)
>
> 1. Turn the helper function parameters into local variables; their
>      initial values are the same as the initial values for the call to
>      the helper function from the main function.
> 2. The continue test is the same as the test in the helper function,
>      for the direction that causes a tail-recursive call to be made. (If
>      the tail-recursive call appears in the else part of the if, then add
>      a call to not.)
> 3. The body uses set! to update the value of each variable; the values
>      are the same as the arguments passed to the tail-recursive call.
> 4. Return the value of the accumulator; this comes after the while
>      loop.

Source: [Tail recursion and loops](http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~comp210/96spring/Labs/lab09.html)

Comment: Ok. But how should it look if i want it to be iterative?

Comment: Sounds like homework.  I've updated answer with sufficient help for you to be able to complete yourself.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. It's not homework. I'm having a test on Wendesday and I'm trying to uderstand this things.The only problem is how to make an accumulator? I don't have numbers, only #f and #t :) so to find the answer I need to usi (and) or tu build a list and find out if there is #t then ouput #f. With these I have to do recursive.

Comment: @CudelcuMedvidekEmilek Not all tail-recursive/iterative functions need an accumulator. In particular, short-circuiting boolean functions (such as `andmap`/`every?` and `ormap`/`any?`) do not require an accumulator. (Your `unique?` function is easily transformable to use `andmap`.)

Comment: Note that SICP distinguishes between procedures (functions) and processes, and refers to a procedure that implements an iterative process as tail-recursive.

Comment: To read more about the point @molbdnilo helpfully makes, see [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html), [**Section 1.2 *Procedures and the Processes They Generate***](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2).

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young So the function is an iteration :) I called itself without anything to improve her.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other two answers explained what and why your function is tail-recursive; I am just going to leave an easy way for beginners to remember the difference:

A **tail**-*recursive function* **does not** *operate* on the recursive call.

A **non**-*tail-recursive function* **does** *operate* on the recursive call.